# If $A,B,C$ are three sets then prove that $A\cap (B\Delta C)=(A\cap B)\Delta (A\cap C)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

If $A,B,C$ are three sets then prove that $A\cap (B\Delta C)=(A\cap B)\Delta (A\cap C)$. (, where $B\Delta C=(B\cup C)-(B\cap C)$)

My solution goes like this:

> We must show $$A\cap (B\Delta C)\subset (A\cap B)\Delta (A\cap C)$$ and $$(A\cap B)\Delta (A\cap C)\subset A\cap (B\Delta C)$$. So, if $x\in A\cap(B\Delta C)$, then $x\in A $ and $(B\Delta C)$ which means $x\in A$ and $[(x\in B$ or $x\in C) $ and $(x\notin B $ or $x\notin C)]$.Thus,$x\in A$ and $x\in B$ or $x\in A $ and $x\in C$ and $(x\notin A $ or $x\notin B$ or $x\notin C )$, which means $x\in (A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C)$ and $(x\notin A\cap B\cap C)$. So, $x\in (A\cap B)\Delta (A\cap C)$. Thus we conclude that ,  $$A\cap (B\Delta C)\subset (A\cap B)\Delta (A\cap C)$$. Now if ,$$x\in (A\cap B)\Delta (A\cap C)$$. We can say, $x\in A$ and $x\in B$ or $x\in A$ and $x\in C$ and $(x\notin A$ or $x\notin B$ or $x\notin C)$. So, $x\in A$ and $(x\in B$ or $x\in C$ and $x\notin B$ or $x\notin C)$. Thus, we can say, $x\in A$ and $(x\in B\cup C$ and $x\notin B\cap C)$. So, $x\in A$ and $(x\in B\Delta C)$. Thus $x\in A\cap (B\Delta C)$. So, $$(A\cap B)\Delta (A\cap C)\subset A\cap (B\Delta C)$$. Thus, we can conclude that $A\cap (B\Delta C)=(A\cap B)\Delta (A\cap C)$.

I want to know whether the proof is correct or not. Is there any other way to do this? Is the proof valid?

Comment: At first glance it looks valid to me. Proofs like this can typically be made shorter with bidirectional inferences, e.g.$$(x\in A)\land((x\in B)\ne(x\in C))\iff((x\in A\land x\in B)\ne(x\in A\land x\in C)).$$You can also make your approach less wordy with a truth table on $x\in A$ etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I propose a more clear proof, based on De Morgan's formulae.

$B\bigtriangleup\,C=(B\bigcup\,C)\bigcap\,(B\bigcap\,C)^{c}$=$(B\bigcup\,C)\bigcap\,(B^{c}\bigcup\,C^{c})$=$(C\bigcap\,B^{c})\bigcup\,(C^{c}\bigcap\,B)$. Hence

$A\bigcap\,(B\bigtriangleup\,C)=(A\bigcap\,C\bigcap\,B^{c})\bigcup\,(A\bigcap\,C^{c}\bigcap\,B)\,\,\,\,\,$$(1)$.

Now we consider $(A\bigcap\,B)\bigtriangleup\,(A\bigcap\,C)$. This is equal to $((A\bigcap\,B)\bigcup\,(A\bigcap\,C)/(A\bigcap\,B\,\bigcap\,C)$

=$(A\bigcap\,(B\bigcup\,C))\bigcap(A\bigcap\,B\,\bigcap\,C)^{c}$=$(A\bigcap\,(B\bigcup\,C))\bigcap(A^{c}\bigcup\,B^{c}\,\bigcup\,C^{c})$

=$\varnothing\,\bigcup\,(B^{c}\bigcap(A\bigcap\,(B\bigcup\,C))\,\bigcup\,(C^{c}\,\bigcap\,(A\,\bigcap\,(B\,\bigcup\,C))$=

$[B^{c}\,\bigcap\,A\,\bigcap\,(B\,\bigcup\,C)]\,\bigcup\,[C^{c}\bigcap\,A\bigcap\,(B\bigcup\,C)]$=$(B^{c}\bigcap\,A\,\bigcap\,C)\bigcup\,(C^{c}\,\bigcap\,A\,\bigcap\,B)\,\,\,\,$$(2)$.

By $(1),(2)$ we get the result.

Comment: Can u please explain how did u conclude that $(A\bigcap\,(B\bigcup\,C))\bigcap(A\bigcap\,B\,\bigcap\,C)^{c}$=$$(A\bigcap\,(B\bigcup\,C))\bigcap(A^{c}\bigcup\,B^{c}\,\bigcup\,C^{c})

=\varnothing\,\bigcup\,(B^{c}\bigcap(A\bigcap\,(B\bigcup\,C))\,\bigcup\,(C^{c}\,\bigcap\,(A\,\bigcap\,(B\,\bigcup\,C))$$...?

Comment: By De Morgan formula the complement of the intersection is the union of the complements. If this is what you are asking.

Comment: Actually  I wanted to know from where are u getting that null set ? Or more specifically how did u conclude  $$(A\bigcap\,(B\bigcup\,C))\bigcap(A^{c}\bigcup\,B^{c}\,\bigcup\,C^{c})$$

=$$\varnothing\,\bigcup\,(B^{c}\bigcap(A\bigcap\,(B\bigcup\,C))\,\bigcup\,(C^{c}\,\bigcap\,(A\,\bigcap\,(B\,\bigcup\,C))$$....?

Comment: I intersect every set of the union $A^{c}\bigcup\,\,B^{c}\bigcup\,C^{c}$ with the set $A\,\bigcap\,(B\,\bigcup\,C)$ and  take the union. The first intersection is the empty set.

Comment: That makes sense! And what about the last part where u wrote $$[B^{c}\,\bigcap\,A\,\bigcap\,(B\,\bigcup\,C)]\,\bigcup\,[C^{c}\bigcap\,A\bigcap\,(B\bigcup\,C)]$$=$$(B^{c}\bigcap\,A\,\bigcap\,C)\bigcup\,(C^{c}\,\bigcap\,A\,\bigcap\,B)\,\,\,\,$$(2).... How did u conclude this?

Comment: Because again the $(B^{c}\,\bigcap\,A)\,\bigcap\,B=\varnothing$

Comment: Thanks a lot...I do get it now....Thank you so much.....